# New windows covered by top panel

Tags: unity, 11.10

After update from 11.04 to 11.10 I experience a disturbing bug:

New windows are always positioned at the top of the screen behind the top panel instead of being aligned to the bottom of the panel.

It could seem to be a minor bug, but it is really disturbing to hunt the window panel anytime I want move the window. Is there any quick fix/settings available?

Thanks

PS: I wanted to attach screenshots, but the system don't let me.

Comment: Have you tried CompizConfigSettingsManager>Windows Management>Place Windows? I have this happening in 11.04 with a third Writer document window opening above the first Writer document window and hence, under the top panel. This did not happen (to me) in 11.10 which I have been using since beta 2 so I never tried finding a permenant fix.

Comment: Yeah actually I've fixed it exactly how you say couple of minutes ago and was going to write it here :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Answer approved by OP in comments.*

> Have you tried `CompizConfigSettingsManager-> Windows Management-> Place
>   Windows` ? I have this happening in 11.04 with a third Writer document
>   window opening above the first Writer document window and hence, under
>   the top panel. This did not happen (to me) in 11.10 which I have been
>   using since beta 2 so I never tried finding a permenant fix.